# Excel Run macros on the last week of month

Tags: vba, excel

I need to call specific function if it is last week of current month. 
Like:

```
    if  today = 31/09/2018 - 7 days 
    call function1
    end if
```

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to determine which is the last day of the month. Therefore you can use the function `GetLastDayOfMonth` as shown below.

Then you need to calculate the difference between today and the `LastDayOfMonth` to check if it is less or equal 7 days.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub IsTodayInLastWeekOfMonth()
    Dim LastDayOfMonth As Date
    LastDayOfMonth = GetLastDayOfMonth(Date) 'Date is always the date of today

    Dim DayDifference As Long
    DayDifference = DateDiff("d", Date, LastDayOfMonth)

    If DayDifference >= 0 And DayDifference <= 7 Then
        'today is less then 7 days from the end of month
    End If
End Sub

Public Function GetLastDayOfMonth(inputDate As Date) As Date
    Dim dYear As Integer
    dYear = Year(inputDate)

    Dim dMonth As Integer
    dMonth = Month(inputDate)

    GetLastDayOfMonth = DateSerial(dYear, dMonth + 1, 0)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you define your work partly. You can use EOMONTH to get the end of the month and then DATEADD to remove a week. I have added + 1 to move into the 7 days upto an including end point.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim d As Long
    d = CLng(Date)

    If d >= DateAdd("ww", -1, Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(d, 0)) + 1 And d <= Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(d, 0) Then
        Call yourSub
    End If   
End Sub
```

---

As a function:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim d As Long
    d = CLng(Date)
    If IsInLastWeek(d) Then
        'Call yourSub
        MsgBox "We made it!"
    End If
End Sub
Public Function IsInLastWeek(ByVal datum As Long) As Boolean
    If datum >= DateAdd("ww", -1, Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(datum, 0)) + 1 And datum <= Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(datum, 0) Then
        IsInLastWeek = True
    End If
End Function
```